# 2 UITableViews inside 1 UIViewController both loading from CoreData

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3, xcode8, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm attempting to have 2 separate UITableViews inside of 1 UIViewController, but the trick is that I'm trying to do it so they both load from CoreDate.

I was trying to accomplish it by using the same style I would with UITableViewController, but I seem to be running into issues with that.

The way I'm getting my data for the tables is using a FRC (NSFetchedResultsController) but it would seem I'm only aloud to have 1 of those per UIViewController.

Here are my 2 FRC fetchers I'm using.

FRC 1:

```
func getFRCIngredients() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Ent_Ingredients> {

    let fetchReq: NSFetchRequest<Ent_Ingredients> = Ent_Ingredients.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recipeRel == %@", self.recipe!)

    fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchReq.predicate = predicate

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchReq, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return frc
}
```

FRC 2:

```
func getFRCDirections() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Ent_Directions> {

    let fetchReq: NSFetchRequest<Ent_Directions> = Ent_Directions.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recipeRel == %@", self.recipe!)

    fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchReq.predicate = predicate

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchReq, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return frc
}
```

I get the error inside the `viewDidLoad()` after I try to set the delegate on the 2nd FRC to be self. Which makes sense when I think about it, you probably can't have it managing two separate sets of data.
Error: "`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    tableViewIngredients.dataSource = self
    tableViewIngredients.delegate = self
    tableViewIngredients.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "recipeIngredientCell")

    tableViewDirections.dataSource = self
    tableViewDirections.delegate = self
    tableViewDirections.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "recipeDirectionCell")

    recipeName.text = recipe!.name
    recipeImage.image = UIImage(data: recipe!.image as! Data)

    oldName = recipe!.name!

    frcIngredients = getFRCIngredients()
    frcIngredients!.delegate = self

    do {
        try frcIngredients!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to perform initial FRC fetch for Ingredients")
    }

    frcDirections = getFRCDirections()
    frcDirections!.delegate = self  //<- ***ERRORS HERE***

    do {
        try frcDirections!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to perform initial FRC fetch for Ingredients")
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AddRecipesVC.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do here? I'm still relatively new to Xcode and Swift so any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had made a silly error. I forgot that I had not updated the attributes names in the `Ent_Directions` Entity, so I was always calling an attribute that didn't exist. But Just in case this helps someone later on, this is the code I ended up using to get the 2 UITableViews working in the single UIViewController. I removed the extra code that didn't pertain to the UITableViews.

Swift 3.0:

```
class EditRecipesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,  NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: - Constants and Variables

    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var frcIngredients: NSFetchedResultsController<Ent_Ingredients>?
    var frcDirections: NSFetchedResultsController<Ent_Directions>?
    var recipe: Ent_Recipes?

    // MARK: - Class Loading Functions

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        tableViewIngredients.dataSource = self
        tableViewIngredients.delegate = self
        tableViewIngredients.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableViewIngredients.estimatedRowHeight = 40

        tableViewDirections.dataSource = self
        tableViewDirections.delegate = self
        tableViewDirections.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableViewDirections.estimatedRowHeight = 40

        recipeName.text = recipe!.name
        recipeImage.image = UIImage(data: recipe!.image as! Data)

        oldName = recipe!.name!

        frcIngredients = getFRCIngredients()
        frcIngredients!.delegate = self

        do {
            try frcIngredients!.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to perform initial FRC fetch for Ingredients")
        }

        frcDirections = getFRCDirections()
        frcDirections!.delegate = self

        do {
            try frcDirections!.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to perform initial FRC fetch for Ingredients")
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AddRecipesVC.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Outlets and Actions

    @IBOutlet var tableViewIngredients: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var tableViewDirections: UITableView!

    // MARK: - Table View Data Source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>

        if (tableView == tableViewIngredients) {
            frc = frcIngredients as! NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>
        } else {
            frc = frcDirections as! NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>
        }

        if let sections = frc.sections {
            return sections.count
        }

        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>

        if (tableView == tableViewIngredients) {
            frc = frcIngredients as! NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>
        } else {
            frc = frcDirections as! NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>
        }

        if let sections = frc.sections {
            let currentSection = sections[section]
            return currentSection.numberOfObjects
        }

        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (tableView == tableViewIngredients) {
            let cell: RecipeIngredientTVCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeIngredientCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeIngredientTVCell

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell: RecipeDirectionTVCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeDirectionCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeDirectionTVCell

            return cell
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Custom Functions

    func getFRCIngredients() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Ent_Ingredients> {

        let fetchReq: NSFetchRequest<Ent_Ingredients> = Ent_Ingredients.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recipeRel == %@", self.recipe!)

        fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchReq.predicate = predicate

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchReq, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        return frc
    }

    func getFRCDirections() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Ent_Directions> {

        let fetchReq: NSFetchRequest<Ent_Directions> = Ent_Directions.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recipeRel == %@", self.recipe!)

        fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchReq.predicate = predicate

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchReq, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        return frc
    }
}
```